# Applying css animation to div

Tags: html, css

I've created a div with a background image in css and I want the div/image to have an automatic fade in and fade out effect.

I've gathered the css animation for this to work however I have no idea as to how I can combine the css of the animation with my current div's css. So here is what I have so far

**HTML**

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.image {
content:url(http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png);
float:left;
}
```

**Animation CSS**

```
    @-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
img {
    -webkit-animation: blink 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink 1s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation: blink 1s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Comment: You're using the wrong selectors. Your HTML has a div element with the ID of "image", but your CSS is targeting an element with a class of "image" while you're assigning the animation to the `<img>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the div with the background image.

- `#image` targets `<div id="image">`
- `.image` targets `<div class="image">`
- `img` targets `<img>`

You can [read more on CSS selectors over at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/hupev/1/edit)

CSS

```
#image {
    -webkit-animation: blink 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink 3s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation: blink 3s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

You should also specify a `background-image` *instead* of using `content`:

**Note:** If there is no content in your div you need to specify a width and height in order to see the background image. By default, the image will be repeated - using `no-repeat` will have the image only displayed once. [Read more on CSS backgrounds here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)

[Same example but with a background image.](http://jsbin.com/hupev/2/edit)

```
div#image {
    background:url(http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png) no-repeat;
    height: 95px;
    width: 280px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Hey I don't use background url because it doesn't work for me for some reason, but thanks for the answer and referring me to selectors! Appreciate it.

Comment: You need to give it a width and height if there is no content in the div. Look at my example link at the bottom of my answer :)

Comment: No problem, [this article about CSS backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) could also be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your CSS.

1. Your div have `id="image"`. But you selected `div.image` instead of `div#image`
2. You applied the animation property on `img` instead on your div.

The proper CSS would be

```
div#image {
    content:url(http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png);
    float:left;
    -webkit-animation: blink 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink 1s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation: blink 1s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes blink {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/r2nt24m3/)**

Comment: Oh I see where I went wrong. Thanks a lot! Appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

A part of your css code if for the `<blink>` element and it works if you change it accordingly.

Take a look at my example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8orbvnt/).

Comment: Example from w3.org - [No, really, don't use it. It's simply evil.](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/blink)

Comment: @misterManSam: that's got to be the best documentation, and advice, available for `<blink>` :)